# Fake linux as android device

Tags: networking, android

How can I let my GNU/linux completely mimic an android device when connecting to a wireless Access Point?

I explain: I moved to another location and it seems that my android phone and tablet have a wireless internet connection of more than **20mbps**. However, this does not happen with my main computer, which for some reason is restricted to 0.5 mbps at best, and usually around **0.2 mbps**, using exactly the same wireless connection as my phone. This is not a GNU/Linux-side problem, because it works perfectly with any other wireless AP. I suspect it's some sort of network restriction and I would like to find out more about it, because this is the first time I encounter it. Tethering does not work on my android devices.

Is this restriction a common practice by network administrators?

With the help of the commentators I have tried:

- Changing hostname to something like `android-713d51a9d238cfcb`
- Changing MAC address
- Changing program that I use for downloads (`wget`)
- My mobile device has user agent `"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"`. I tried the same with `wget` and chrome but nothing works.

I note that `ping` appears to have the same performance between computer and android device.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
I posted the results from the script on [pastebin (please click this link)](http://pastebin.com/UDmvjeJP) and I will certainly change the title of my question when we seem to arrive at some conclusion.
To my surprise after running the wireless-script I also did a [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net). My Computer had ~3.5Mbps Download and ~20Mbps Upload, while my android ~20Mbps for Download and ~20Mbps Upload.

Comment: Have you tried switching of your phone and tablet, to see if they interfere with the quality of the main computers wireless?

Comment: Or try changing your MAC address of your computer as your Android phone. Give it a try.

Comment: How far is your computer from the access point? What type of WiFi does it support? Does the connection get better if you move it? My old 802.11b notebook computer only runs at 1/10 the speed of my phone and tablet in one room of my house because there's a big piece of metal (my kitchen stove) in the way.

Comment: Anthon, Yes, I just did. Ruban, I also did this. @MarkPlotnick the computer has a TP-Link TL-WN722N usb dongle, which I can move freely with a 3m USB extension cable, so this is not the problem. AP is no more than 7 meters away, and there is almost a clear line of sight between the dongle's and AP's antennae.

Comment: Does MAC Spoofing helped?

Comment: I bet it detects the User Agent, try with WGET on both phone and PC

Comment: I tried `wget ftp://ftp.famous-BSD-Release.iso` and it is over 1 MB/sec on phone, and under 10KB/sec on computer.

Comment: @LatinSuD I tried with `wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"  ftp://***/pub/DesktopBSD/Releases/1.7/DesktopBSD-1.7-amd64.iso` on PC but it did not help. Situation is crazy, phone downloads with more than 1MB/sec and computer with less than 20KB/sec :(

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - your B class wifi only operates at a 1/10 of the speed because the N class adapters hog bandwidth - they aggregate ip frames into single packets. There's also the possibility of a 40MHz wideband config which would only be noise to your B adapter - but that is generally disabled by default. And there's MIMO - multiple-in multiple-out - but multi-antenna handhelds are rare, I'd wager.

Comment: @mikeserv I think you will save the day once again. I do not understand your comment so please allow me to clarify a bit. For my computer I use a `TP-Link TL-WN722n` with `AR9271 802.11n` (exactly this one: http://goo.gl/Ei8Qmu and including its external omni antenna). On my previous location (home) it did not have problem to reach more than 1MB/sec, but this area has a lot of wireless users (no more than 10). How can my Nexus 4 adapter have so much better download capacity at the exact same spot as my wifi USB dongle?

Comment: That antenna is shit, I'm sorry to say. Plus it's on the bus - there's a *lot* of noise there - I mean gigaherz, guy. You've gotta think of it like this: the wifi router can shout as loud and as clear as it wants, but the wifi card - your dongle - has to talk back. So, basically, all of the other stations get in first. Radio is radio is radio. So you need to get it away from the computer. And you need to shape its signal. A coffee can - an old mini-satellite dish is best - a collander. [Inspiration maybe?](https://www.google.com/search?q=coffee+can+usb+dongle+wifi+antenna&tbm=isch)

Comment: Think - parabolic. And by the way, I have never *saved the day*. [Mighty Mouse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsPa8QgGGkc)... on the other hand... *gets the situation well in hand*...

Comment: Thinking twice - it's probably a driver thing too. I'm willing to bet your adapter is supported, but not in N mode. You're probably operating G at best. And N devices - such as your phone - are *greedy*. They'll beat out a G every time - especially in a 40MHz band, which will only confuse and inhibit most G devices which expect a 20MHz band. There's a way to check - I think with `iwlwifi` - but it's been awhile. I like wires.

Comment: I have some overkill experience with antennas/feeders and dishes for this matter. Once I constructed (with soldering, wires etc.) ~10 hand-made dipole panel-type antennas. It never occurred to me that it might be an antenna-issue. First because I connect the TPLink with a 8m cable and changed positions/orientation/etc and then because I perhaps mistakenly thought phone wifi antennas would not be as strong as my USB Dongles'. If the reason is this and not software related I will (#(@)&% my self and worship you as a god :D

Comment: But those phone antennas are like - *the whole phone*. If you've got mean on one you'll torn up some foil kinda stuff under the battery - that's all antenna. Plus they always locate the processor on the other end of the phone and there's *tons* of shielding. I've got mean on a lot em. But not my Nexus 4.

Comment: Oh and last - have you considered just plugging the Nexus 4 into the computer and piggybacking it? That 8m cable doesn't bode well for my suggestion. Still, if you've the coffee can, the pen-knife, and the knuckle-skin to spare, it won't cost much to try.

Comment: I think that you are approaching the problem the wrong way, can you run this script `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` ([source](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/169736)) and add the information to your question.

Comment: @user2383408 ^this guy^ might save the day

Comment: Sorry at this point the title of this question seems to be wrong: Your driver/hardware on the PC seem to have a bug. It has nothing to do with anybody detecting the operating system.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks. If I get that laptop back (it was a loaner), I'll try it with all my N devices turned off.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - it's probably better off where it is, then. You don't want a B class adapter in anything if you can help it.

Comment: Nothing useful from my pastebin I suppose, right? Pf!...

Answer (score 2):

This procedure is known as MAC Spoofing.

Under GNU/Linux, the MAC address of a network interface card (NIC) can be changed by following the procedures below.

***Note: Before removing your GNU/linux MAC Address, you should take backup of the machine MAC Address.***

NOTE: MAC addresses used within this article are provided for example only. Substitute according to your requirements.
NOTE: Commands below MUST be executed with root privileges (e.g. prepended with "sudo "), in order for things to work!

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
ifconfig eth0 hw ether MAC-Address-of-your-Android-phone
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

Execute

> ifconfig eth0

to confirm.

To find MAC Address of your Android phone follow the steps below,

1. Please follow these instructions to find the MAC Address of your
   Android phone or tablet:
2. Press the Home button at the bottom of the phone.
3. Press the Menu button.
4. Tap Settings.
5. Tap Wireless & Networks.
6. If Wi-Fi is not already selected, tap Wi-Fi to turn it on.
7. Press the Back button.
8. Tap About Phone.
9. Tap Status.

and note your Android device MAC Address.

***Important Notice: Revert your GNU/linux MAC address when your done browsing. So that you may not encounter problems with other Android apps.***

Attribution
1. [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20change%20mac%20address%20in%20linux&oq=how%20to%20change%20mac%20address%20in%20l&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.17527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20find%20mac%20address%20in%20android) 
2. [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux)

Comment: Thank you for your support.  It still does not work. Android is originally `4c:21:d0:4c:c0:a5`, and TP-Link dongle `90:f6:52:cc:49:4b`. It took me some time to do this because I had to use `ifconfig wlan0 down` `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 4c:21:d0:4c:c0:a5` `ifconfig wlan0 up`. But when I was connecting, dongle's MAC was reverting to the original one! I found out it was soft-blocked (details at http://askubuntu.com/questions/98702/how-to-unblock-something-listed-in-rfkill) which fixed it. And then connected properly using `wpa_supplicant`, but speed is still awful.

Comment: `net-tools` hasn't had a release in over a decade, and has been soundly deprecated by `iproute2`.